# Scrolling and updating the view in OnLButtonUp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, scroll

I have one case in which when I selects a toolbar item and selects region on the view with auto-scroll provided. Then I creates a dialog of same size of that of selected region at the same position as that of the selected region.

But thing gets worse when selected region is bigger than that of the workspace/screen or the top-left corner are not visible on the screen. Then in that case the dialog's top-left are out of the screen.

I am doing all these in `OnLButtonUp()` event handler.

**Question:**

Is it possible to scroll the view so that top-left corner become visible.
And then draw the dialog as the new scrolled visible view.

Any suggestion/advice will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the device points and logical point will solve your problem. You should use the conversions like DptoLp and LptoDP etc